# How do I unselect outside of react-select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

How do I unselect outside of react-select?

I display the selected options in react-select isMulti, in a separate block, but I have a problem, how to unselect in  itself by onClick in the block where I display the options?

```
const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState([]);
  return (
    <>
      <Select
        options={options}
        isMulti
        hideSelectedOptions={false}
        controlShouldRenderValue={false}
        onChange={(e) => setSelectedOptions(e)}
      />
      {selectedOptions.map((item) => (
        <div onClick={//unselect}>{item.label}</div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the 'filter' function on arrays? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter  Since selectedOptions is an array you should be able to just filter out the current item in your onClick handler and call setSelectedOptions with the resulting array.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a handler and filter the values from the array.

You should also control Select value with the state values if you don't want to have an unexpected behaviour between components (because if you remove an element from the div list you should pass the new list to the Select component).

Hope this code snippet could help.

```
const options = [
  {
    id: 1,
    value: "Option 1",
    label: "Option 1",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: "Option 2",
    label: "Option 2"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    value: "Option 3",
    label: "Option 3"
  }
];

const SelectComponent = (props) => {
  const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState([]);

  const handleDeleteOption = (id) => {
    setSelectedOptions(prevSelectedOptions => {
      return prevSelectedOptions.filter(option => option.id !== id)
    })
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Select
        options={options}
        isMulti
        hideSelectedOptions={false}
        controlShouldRenderValue={false}
        value={selectedOptions}
        onChange={(e) => setSelectedOptions(e)}
      />
      {selectedOptions.map((item) => (
        <div onClick={() => { handleDeleteOption(item.id) }}>{item.label}</div>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}
```